# How do I full-screen my CMD?

Tags: windows, command-line, putty

I work a **LOT** in the windows command line. Unlike other windows, it doesn't maximize - it just goes a big as it can depending on the buffer size. Is there any way I can get the CMD to act like the PuTTY console, flowing with the resize?

---

NOTE: The answer doesn't have to be a tweak to the CMD. If there's a PuTTY-like program out there that will work between me and the command line I'm happy with that - I just want a proper window to work in

Comment: @Codemonkey: The problem is, if the program uses a *true* console, then it can't flow. If it *mimics* a console (like PuTTy), then it will necessarily fail to work well with some programs, i.e. ones that use low-level console I/O. Which do you prefer?

Comment: Who says I can't use both? :-)

Comment: Ah I see, so you just need the latter, right? (CMD is already the former.)

Comment: I never really use it, but I think PowerShell should have a bit more flexibility.

Comment: I'm doing PHP and Python coding, so for all I know I only need the latter, yes. I'm thinking that if I were to ever need the former, I'd just use CMD :-) It's be awesome to have a proper command prompt window though

Comment: try also dosbox

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/160134/full-screen-dos-in-windows-7

Comment: On Windows 10, simply resize the Window :)

Comment: This one is more general than the Vista-specific https://superuser.com/questions/7219/fullscreen-vistas-command-prompt-or-replacement. Could we swap the duplicate, so that we can post a new answer here?

Comment: Yeah, once the darn thing is fullscreen, you don't have a title bar that you can use to get the properties to get it off-fullscreen. *Alt* + *Enter* is then your savior.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's a bit tricky, but you can make the cmd fullscreen:

1. Launch the CMD and write the following code:

   ```
   mode 800
   ```
2. Now you can make it fullscreen by pull the menubar to the top of the screen or resize it, to whatever size you want.

**If you want, that this is set by default, do the following:**

1. Open an editor and write in the code

   ```
   @Echo Off
   mode 800
   ```
2. Now change the filename to `.cmd` or `.bat`
3. Put it in the autostart.
   To put it in the autostart for **all users**, do the following:

   1. Go to the registry by entering `regedit.exe` in the windows-searchfield.
   2. Go to the following path:

      ```
      HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor
      ```
   3. *Optional*: If you want to do it just for the actual user, go to the following path:

      ```
      HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor
      ```
   4. Now add a key from type REG-SZ with the name `Autorun` and put the path of the script in the data-section of the key.
      [image]
   5. Now you have to change the value of the value. Rightclick on the key and choose `edit`.
      [image]
   6. Now set the value to the path, where your script is:
      [image]

Everytime you now launch your machine, your cmd will be able to go fullscreen.

Comment: This spawns scrollbars and the text doesn't wrap, but it's still the best solution I've seen so far!

Comment: Yes, it's a workaround. I dont know, why microsoft doesn't implement fullscreen ability.

Comment: @codemonkey, you can use '''mode 160''' or can test other number that matches desktop width without scrollbars...

Comment: @c0dev, I liked your solution :)

Answer (score 19):

1. Open CMD
2. Right click on titlebar and choose "properties"
3. In "layout" tab, in "screen buffer size" change from 80 to a number that will fit your screen width. E.g., in my notebook a CMD window is the half of my computer screen in width, so I choose 160.
4. Maximize window and see if appears an horizontal scroll bar at bottom or if there are more space on the right. If so repeat step 3 using other widths (for me 158 functioned).
5. In layout tab, copy values from "screen buffer size" to "windows size". Height will be locked to the maximum allowed (in mine case, 61) and it is done.
6. Trick: if you want, for some reason, maintain original size of CMD window, create a link (or a lot of links) for CMD with different size.  E.g., in my desktop there are two shortcuts for CMD. One is a shortut for "CMD" named "CMD - original". The other is a shortcut for "CMD /k cd \" named "CMD - big", with those sizes for fullscreen (158x61).

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: This answer is obvious and doesn't address the "flowing with the resize" part of my question, but it's still the best solution. Damn windows

Comment: This is a much simpler method ("wmic" trick): **1.** Open CMD **2.** Execute `wmic` **3.** At the `wmic:root\cli>` prompt maximize the window **4.** Right click on titlebar and choose "Properties" **5.** Copy "Window wide" to "Buffer wide" and increment "Window height" by 2 **6.** Click "Accept" **7.** Enter `exit`

Comment: @Aacini, use your comment as one more answer.

Answer (score 7):

On most computers, **Alt + Enter** should let you enter or exit full screen. Note that this will hide your taskbar too.

Comment: Not on 64-bit...

Comment: Or 32-bit from Vista upwards I think. Was definitely applicable on XP though.

Comment: Screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/j9aRm.png . Interesting, I never knew that.  And that must be the reason why my Print Shop/New Print Shop (circa 1989/1993) won't run in W7 either!  Wonder how to get them working...?

Comment: @therube: See http://superuser.com/questions/160134/full-screen-dos-in-windows-7.

Comment: @therube If you have Windows 7 Professional or Ultimate, Google "Windows XP mode", install it, then install Print Shop inside the XP virtual machine it creates. Works practically the same.

Comment: In XP, you could (manually) install the *Full screen video driver for console* device, but it is no longer available in Vista+ (and even if you manually copy and install it, it won’t work). `>:-|` (And yet, games are able to switch screen modes as they please.)

Comment: I'd like to add here that Windows 10 x64 supports ALT+ENTER for console nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

Open cmd.exe
Right click on the title bar
click properties
click layout
adjust to your liking.

Comment: That doesn't make the text flow as the window is resized...

Answer (score 0):

No, the Windows architecture simply doesn't understand what "flowing text" means, in the console.

It would need to provide support for *pseudo-TTY*, but it doesn't: https://jdebp.eu./FGA/capture-console-win32.html

Comment: Updated my question

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shortcut with the following content:

> `PowerShell -WindowStyle Hidden -Command "Start-Process cmd -WindowStyle Maximized"`